# How to compute every array values of two foreach in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

Hello is there a way to get the difference of two foreach in laravel or php. Here's my sample code

```
    @foreach($budgets as $budget)
         $budget->b_amount
    @endforeach

    @foreach($purchases as $purchase)
       $purchase->p_amount
    @endforeach
```

So basically I am in need to get all the values of each foreach and then take the difference of each. Is there any way to do this? Something like this...

```
 <?php 
  $diff =  $budget->b_amount - $purchase->p_amount;
 ?>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: The difference of the totals of each array? Is that what you want?  (sample data, and the desired result, would be especially helpful)

Comment: yes the  difference of each array.

Comment: You're still not being clear. Are you saying you want to take the first value from the $budgets array and subtract it from the first value from the $purchases array? And then do that for the second values, and then the third, and so on?

Comment: Yes exactly Sir @NathanHeffley. Sorry for not being clear. Hope you dont mind. Thanks thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if(count($budgets) == count($purchases))
@foreach($budgets as $key => $value)
     $diff[] = $budgets[$key]->b_amount - $purchases[$key]->p_amount
@endforeach
@endif
```

now `$diff` contains array of differences.

Comment: @kalawadei  do not forget to select  my answer as accepted if it is the answer you were looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you can ensure all object inside the array is numeric value, you may use below function:

```
function diff($budgets, $purchases) {
    $b = 0;
    $p = 0;
    foreach ($budgets as $budget) {
        $b += $budget;
    }
    foreach ($purchases as $purchase) {
        $p += $purchase;
    }
    return $b-$p;
}
```

Besides, if you only need the diff neglect the +/- sign:

```
function diff($budgets, $purchases) {
    $b = 0;
    $p = 0;
    foreach ($budgets as $budget) {
        $b += $budget;
    }
    foreach ($purchases as $purchase) {
        $p += $purchase;
    }
    return abs($b-$p);
}
```

However, if you not sure whether a numeric value is inside the array:

```
function diff($budgets, $purchases) {
    $b = 0;
    $p = 0;
    foreach ($budgets as $budget) {
        $b += is_numeric($budget)?$budget:0;
    }
    foreach ($purchases as $purchase) {
        $p += is_numeric($purchase)?$purchase:0;
    }
    return $b-$p;
}
```